# ${1\over x}+{1\over y}+{1\over z}={1\over {x+y+z}}$

Tags: algebra-precalculus

if $${1\over x}+{1\over y}+{1\over z}={1\over {x+y+z}}$$ then find the value of $${1\over x^7}+{1\over y^7}+{1\over z^7}$$

Comment: You need to provide some context (where the problem is from, what you have tried), else your question is likely to soon be closed.

Comment: I have tried based on hit-trial method.But unable to find solution after simplification of given information.

Comment: Robert Israel gave you a key hint. In the future, you should try to include your work (even if incomplete) as part of your question.

Comment: Where is the problem from?

Answer (score 3):

Hint: From the given equation, show that $(x+y)(x+z)(y+z)=0$.